# Query isn't getting executed

Tags: php, mysqli

Can some onw please explain what is wrong with this ... this worked completely fine with procedural php

```
function foo(){
    $incomingtime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
    $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
    $id = "Abc123" ;
    $u_id = 1;
    $c_id = 1;
    $query = "INSERT INTO table (indate, myid, uniqueid, commonid) 
              VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('ssii', $incomingtime, $id, $u_id, $c_id);

    $stmt->execute();
    printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", $db->affected_rows);   // Always return 1
    $stmt->close();
}
```

But nothing goes in the database.

Datatype in mysql db for indate is `datetime`

Comment: What do you mean by "procedural PHP", can you give us the so called working code

Comment: with procedural i meant php4 and mysql connector

Comment: what is this `$stmt_4->bind_param('ssii',$incomingtime , $id  ,$u_id ,$c_id  );`  Make to `$stmt->bind_param('ssii',$incomingtime , $id  ,$u_id ,$c_id  );`

Comment: Also first you bind params & than you defining variables `$u_id = 1 ;
 $c_id = 1;`.

Comment: @rikesh : I edit with your suggestion...still no use ...
and yes $db is defined well....

I guess the problem is with date ....because queries exclusing this param are working fine

Comment: @Nikhil `$db` is not defined in the above code. Even if it is defined before you call the function. The function is not aware of `$db`

Answer (score 3):

There's several issues with this code.

1. `$stmt_4` is used before it's defined.
2. <s>`$u_id` and `$c_id` are both defined then not used.</s>
3. <s>Trying to execute `$stmt` without supplying parameters.</s>
4. `$db` is not defined.
5. `$id` is not defined.

If you are trying to convert working code to a function make sure that either the function gets these passed in as an argument, they are marked as global or the function creates/ retrieves them.

Comment: Hey jim... i have made the edits...consider $db as well defined in my code ...
now can you suggest me with working solution

Comment: @Nikhil, you don't set $db within this scope. If it's defined outside of this function, you have to make it available in this scope - f.e. by using the _global_ definition. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I tried making $db as global but still no use ...

can someone give me a short working snippet how to write proper sql for queries involving datetime datatype as column values ....i had just begun using mysqli ...

Comment: It's worth printing out the $db variable to confirm it exists. The docs have some good examples of using mysqli: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

Check changing:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (indate, myid, uniqueid, commonid) 
          VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ssii', $incomingtime, $id, $u_id, $c_id);
$u_id = 1;
$c_id = 1;
$stmt->execute();
```

to:

```
$u_id = 1;
$c_id = 1;

$query = "INSERT INTO table (indate, myid, uniqueid, commonid) 
          VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?, ?, ?)"
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($id, $u_id, $c_id));
```

**NOTE:** I deleted the parameter `ssii` because it's not considered in the query. It only expects 4 parameters.

Comment: your code gave me :
Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in ......

Comment: Do you have permission to insert in that table with that user/pass?

Comment: yes....I have the permission ...my other query which isn't making use of dates is working fine

Comment: Maybe you can try using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` directly in the query, instead of `indate`. I eddited the post.

Comment: I just realized that you are passing 5 parameters, but the query is expecting 4. What is `ssii`?